# Install Ruby On Rails on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, ubuntu-11.04

I am just a fresher in the field of `Ruby`.I tried to install with the help of this [blog](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/06/27/install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-10-1011-04/) on my `ubuntu 11.04` system.When I was going through the step by step process for installation and I used this command `bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.io/install/rvm)` and after that I used  rvm | head -1 it showed this

```
No command 'rvm' found, but there are 19 similar ones
rvm: command not found
```

So can some one tell me where is the wrong part.I don't know much about Ruby.Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.Any good and easy understandable links for installation of Ruby on `Ubuntu 11.04` will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Comment: Ok that worked..but when again I used `rvm install 1.9.2` it showed something like `No command 'rvm' found, but there are 19 similar ones
rvm: command not found`

Comment: You should add [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" in ~/.bashrc, and restart terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You just follow this and install everything

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

And chill..

Answer (score 1):

Try to install rvm using

```
curl -L http://get.rvm.io | bash
```

This command and then run, read and follow instructions: `rvm requirements`